# How to write point's attribute to polygon table using pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, table, shp-write

test2 is point data and test is polygon data
I will write test2's attribute to test table i want to make it

```
 i want 

 date|Num|add|결과|x|y|BUFF_DIST|contain  
 20170103|640272|강원도 인제군...|정좌표|318102|501346|30000.0000|86,91,235,2485...|
```

I want to use pyqgis and I wrote code but I don't know how to write point's attirbute to polygon table

my code is

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
NF = "FRMHS_NO"
f = iface.addVectorLayer("D:/2018/nonmoon/test/test.shp","test","ogr")
g = iface.addVectorLayer("D:/2018/nonmoon/test/test2.shp","test2","ogr")
f.startEditing()
res = f.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("contain",QVariant.String)])
f.updateFields()
```

I have a image. first img is map
second img is test(polygon data)'s table
last img is test2(point data)'s table

[image: mapping img]
[image: polygon's table]
[image: point's table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [QgsFeature::setAttributes()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html#a83aff02ac2a6cfe15262fa55e1e09b0c) method to set your values for your single feature:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant
NF = "FRMHS_NO"
f = iface.addVectorLayer("D:/2018/nonmoon/test/test.shp","test","ogr")
g = iface.addVectorLayer("D:/2018/nonmoon/test/test2.shp","test2","ogr")
f.startEditing()
res = f.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField("contain",QVariant.String)])
f.updateFields()

# Set attributes according to ordering of fields
for features in f.getFeatures():
    features.setAttributes([123,62,'강원도 인제군...','정좌표',318102,501346,30000.0000,'86,91,235,2485...'])
    f.updateFeature(features)

f.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But i want to write file G 's id field to file F's table that point contain to polygon. No write on one's own

Comment: @박진호 - Have you considered calling the [Join attributes by location](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_general_tools.html?highlight=join%20attributes#id9) tool from the _Processing Framework_?

Comment: @박진호 - If you want point features to contain the polygon columns such as id, use something like: `processing.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', point_layer, polygon_layer, ['intersects'], 0.00, 1, '', 1, output)`

Comment: @박진호 - Yes, first use `import processing` and then you could use the following by adjusting to your paths: `processing.runalg('qgis:joinattributesbylocation', "path/to/point.shp", "path/to/polygon.shp", ['intersects'], 0.00, 1, '', 1, "path/to/output.shp")`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to upgrade this 'Join attribute by location'. I want to have file g's all id number to contain polygon and I add polygon field ('contain') about file g's all id number.
"ex) contain field = 89,91,235,2845...last id number"

Comment: Use python's list??